# Using $setValidity on an element outside of the current scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-forms

I have a global directive, that is in charge of getting the error message from the controller, compiling, and displaying it.

In case there is a server validation error such as 
`This email already exists`, I would like to focus on this element, and set it validity to false, e.g. `$setValidity(false)`.

This directive is not the form, and it doesn't contain the form.

What would you suggest (already tried everything which is commented out)

```
directive('messageCompile', function ( $compile, $window, $rootScope ) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function ( scope, element, attrs ) {
      var el;

      attrs.$observe( 'template', function ( tpl ) {
        if ( angular.isDefined( tpl ) ) {
          // compile the provided template against the current scope
          el = $compile( tpl )( scope );
          // stupid way of emptying the element
          element.html("");

          // add the template content
          element.append( el );
        }
      });
      attrs.$observe('focus', function(val){
        if ( angular.isDefined( val )  && Boolean(val)) {
          var el = angular.element('[name="' + attrs.focus + '"]');
          var form = el.parents().find('form');
          var formName = form.attr('name');
           el.focus();
          // scope[formName].$setValidity(val, false);       
          // el.scope().$setValidity(false);
          // scope[formName][val].$setValidity(false);
          //$rootScope.scope[formName][val].$setValidity(false);
          //$rootScope.scope[formName].$setValidity(val, false);
        }
      });
        var windowEl = angular.element($window);
        windowEl.on('scroll', function() {
          if(window.scrollY > 46){
            element.parent().parent().addClass('stayTop');

            // alert('here');
          }  
          else{
            // alert('here2');
            element.parent().parent().removeClass('stayTop');
          }
        });

    },
  }
}).
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to use `$scope[formName]` the controller must be on the form element. Either by defining directly:

```
<form name="theForm" ng-controller="TheCtrl">
```

Or as a directive:

```
directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        template: "<form name='theForm'>...</form>",
        controller: ["$scope", function($scope) {
            ...
        }],
        ...
    };
});
```

If one these conditions is met, then you have to define the name attribute for every element that you need to access:

```
<form name="theForm" ...>
    <input name="theInput" ...>
```

Then you can access `$setValidity()`, inside the corresponding controller, as defined above:

```
$scope.theForm.theInput.$setValidity(false);
```

AGAIN REMEMBER: In order for a controller to access the form, it must be at the same element as the form, or maybe at a child scope.

Comment: Any way to make a workaround?, maybe a service that is injected to the directive and gets the $scope as a parameter?.
The think is that this directive is a top error bar, and it has nothing to do with the numerous forms that I have on my application

Comment: Maybe you could expose the forms from a controller that is in the appropriate scope. But then you have to take extra care to cleanup those references on route change (generally when the controller goes out of scope). You could also implement this feature with messages; maybe some simple, generic controllers that sit side-by-side with the form (thus have access to it) and listen for specific, `$broadcast`ed messages to trigger `$setValidity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've managed to solve this in a way that gives a sufficient result:

```
attrs.$observe('focus', function(val){
    if (angular.isDefined(val)  && Boolean(val)) {
        var el = angular.element('[name="' + attrs.focus + '"]');
        var form = el.parents().find('form');
        var formName = form.attr('name');
        el.focus();
        el.removeClass('ng-valid').addClass('ng-invalid');
        el.bind('keyup', function(){
            el.removeClass('ng-invalid');
            el.unbind('keyup');
        });
    }
});
```

Of course the keyup event can be replaced by a change event, or any other event.